# how can access to android system level api. (ex. "BluetoothClass.PROFILE_A2DP" and others (function, const, variables))

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

```
private boolean isAudio(BluetoothDevice device) {
        boolean isAudio = false;
        BluetoothClass bluetoothClass = device.getBluetoothClass();

        isAudio = (bluetoothClass.doesClassMatch(BluetoothClass.PROFILE_A2DP) ||
                bluetoothClass.doesClassMatch(BluetoothClass.PROFILE_HEADSET) ||
                bluetoothClass.doesClassMatch(BluetoothClass.PROFILE_HID))
                && !BluetoothA2dpConnection.isRemoconDevice(device);
        return isAudio;
}
```

This is not just a normally java's reference error question.

now i developing for android launcher application.
it's not third party app.
it's for provide android device's default launcher.

so i need to access to system level apis.
my app is own system permissions.
previous version's developer is resign already. i can't ask him.
previous version launcher did access to system level apis.(ex bluetooth)
but when i open this project, android stuido say to me "can not resolve method".

BluetoothClass.PROFILE_A2DP(and others) is android system level api's constants!
how can i access it?
and doesClassMatch method is can't access too.

BluetoothClass and BluetoothDevice Class's package is `android.bluetooth`
(`android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass`)
(`android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice`)

Answer (score -1):

On Android API 33, all of these are available:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass#PROFILE_A2DP

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass#PROFILE_HEADSET

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass#PROFILE_HID

I wonder though what it can be used for.

It's not what's used on the Android OS to determine the icon for each, like here:

[image]

right?